# sql 'is not' ( <> ) is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have no idea what I do wrong... this is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE userId = "6"
OR toUserId = "6"
OR toAll = "1"
AND id <> "4"
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that the 'is not' (<>) is not working, it still returns a result where id is 4. What's the problem?

EDIT: Now I'm stuck with the following problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE (
    userId = "6"
    OR toUserId = "6"
    OR toAll = "1"
)
AND id <> IN ('4','2')
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And again the problem is that the output is false, meaning this doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use parenthesis to indicate operator precedence:

```
WHERE (
       userId   = "6"
    OR toUserId = "6"
    OR toAll    = "1"
)
AND id <> "4"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your Query condition should be like this:

```
WHERE 
(userId = "6" OR toUserId = "6" OR toAll = "1") 
AND (id <> "4")
```

Your query will be evaluated to:

```
WHERE 
  (userId = "6" OR toUserId = "6") OR (toAll = "1" AND id <> "4")
```

Which is not what you want.